# Como retornar un objeto y respuesta en la misma funcion

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, mvc

Tengo un controlador y una vista, que por medio de un boton mandan llamar una funcion de mi controlador, entonces el reporte se genera sin problema, el punto es al retornar ya sea mi reporte para que pueda descargarse o mi respuesta con estatus 200 para la vista.

Inicialmente tenia el boton con un href a la ruta del controlador, e procesaba y descargaba el reporte

Pero ahora necesito de la respuesta de si se descargo, para poner un loading en lo que se hace el proceso en la vista, vaya que al presionar el boton de descargar el reporte, se vea un alert donde se ponga un alert que diga en proceso.. y una vez finalice la descarga se quite el alert,

View:

```
<a href="/download/report/xlsx" v-on:click="loadAlert()">Export Report</a>
```

JS:

```
loadAlert(){

Toast.fire({
icon: 'info',
title:'Preparando reporte..'
})
```

Use axios para que me retornará la respuesta a la view

```
 /*axios.get('/api/download/report/xlsx',{
            params:this.filter
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            if(res.data.status){
                
                 Toast.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: '¡Tu reporte esta listo!'
            });

            }
        }).catch(err => {
            Toast.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: err.toString()
            });
        })  */
```

}

Controlador:

//Omiti la mayor parte en resumem, se procesa y mis returns se ven afectados, porque necesito la respuesta en la vista y necesito expulsar el reporte para el navegador:

```
//return response()->json(array('status' => true, 'message' => __('Exito')));


return (new ProgressExport($params))->download($lang_file_name, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX, [
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache'
]);
```

Dado que uno es un objeto para ser expulsado al navegador y el otro un response en json, no puedo utilizar return array($excelresponse,$statusresponse);, como podria resolverlo, estoy en PHP y JS con Laravel

Answer (score 1):

Encontré una buena solución a esto, en vez de usar 2 respuestas (returns), opte por solo dejar la respuesta de retorno de mi reporte a la vista.

```
return (new ProgressExport($params))->download($lang_file_name, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX, [
            'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache'
        ]);
```

En mi vista solo recibo el estatus pero bien no expulsaba el reporte, decidi modificar un poco la peticion axios, para darle formato al reporte una vez en la vista y de esta manera moldearlo para que fuera expulsado del navegador:

```
      axios.get('/api/export/report/generalxlsx',{
                params:this.filter,
                responseType: 'blob'
            }).then(res => {
               if(res.status == 200){
                   Toast.fire({
                       icon: 'success',
                       title: 'Reporte generado',
                   }).then(function() {
                        let blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });
                        let link = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        let a = document.createElement("a");
                        a.download = "file.xlsx";
                        a.href = link;
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                        document.body.removeChild(a);
                    })
               }//End if
            }).catch(err => {
                Toast.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: err.toString()
                });
            });
```

En los parámetros de la petición agregue como contentType 'blob', seguido después de ejecutar el success como si fuera Ajax, ejecute una función anónima, para crear un nuevo objeto blob, ahí se pasa mi respuesta y empieza a crear el documento y finalemente lo expulsa.

[Laravel Excel File download from Ajax Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66150142/laravel-excel-file-download-from-ajax-request)